# SET length limit on MySQL update statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following update statement:

```
UPDATE home_isilonpath
SET path_end = SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1)
WHERE id > 1512647
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to change the length of my column for `path_end`. How would I update the query to truncate the result at 200 char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE home_isilonpath
SET path_end = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1), 0, 200)
WHERE id > 1512647
```

or, as proposed by tadman:

```
UPDATE home_isilonpath
SET path_end = LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1), 200)
WHERE id > 1512647
```

Comment: There's also the [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function.

Comment: That's even better. (Not updating my post, to not make the comment look stupid.)

Comment: That's fine. Just add it as a second example if you want.